# How to debug why my Cron job is running twice?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, debian

When I execute my cron manually everything seems to work. However when it runs by cron it seems to run twice. In my deployment script I have the following two lines to add my crons:

```
/usr/bin/crontab -l | { /bin/cat; /bin/echo "* 3 * * * /etc/app/execute.py"; } | /usr/bin/crontab -
/usr/bin/crontab -l | { /bin/cat; /bin/echo "* 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /etc/app/solr.py"; } | /usr/bin/crontab -
```

Is there any reasonable reason why my CRON might be running twice on my debian server? I have no idea what might be causing this or how to debug it.

In my Crontab I have this:

```
* 3 * * * /etc/app/execute.py                                                         
* 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /etc/app/solr.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug this by adding something like

```
; echo $(date) ; echo "Cron line one" >> /root/cronlog
```

That way you can see which line was executed when.

Also, how do you edit your cronjobs? With "crontab -e" or by directly editing the files? If you edit the files directly (which I don't recommend), then please compare the content of the files with the output of "crontab -l".

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. The code I used to add the cronjob is in the original question along with the output from crontab -l